# Video resizing with the Video Processor MFT

Tags: c++, video, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

I'm using the video processor MFT for pixel format conversion. That works fine. But when I change the input size and keep the output the same the processing of the input

```
hr = ColorConv->ProcessInput(0, pSample, 0);
```

fails with:

```
The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object.
```

I think I need to make some settings for the video resizer but I can't figure out the minimal conditioins. What I read is that I need to set SetFullCropRegion but that does not exist in MFT (is DMO)? Also setting SetConstrictionSize does not work.

What I have now is.

```
IMFTransform* ColorConv;
...
UINT32 unFlags = MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT | 
    MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SYNCMFT | 
    MFT_ENUM_FLAG_HARDWARE |
    MFT_ENUM_FLAG_LOCALMFT | 
    MFT_ENUM_FLAG_SORTANDFILTER; 

IMFActivate **ppMFTActive;
UINT32 cMFTActive;

hr = MFTEnumEx(MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_PROCESSOR, unFlags, nullptr, nullptr, &ppMFTActive, &cMFTActive);
...
ppMFTActive[0]->ActivateObject(__uuidof(IMFTransform), (void **)&ColorConv);

...

// input:
pMFTInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
pMFTInputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_YUY2);
hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMFTInputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 320, 240);
...
hr = ColorConv->SetInputType(0, pMFTInputMediaType, 0);

// output 
pMFTOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
pMFTOutputMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB24);
hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMFTOutputMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 352, 288);
...
hr = ColorConv->SetOutputType(0, pMFTOutputMediaType, 0);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  It should not be a surprise that the color space converter only supports converting color spaces, rather than performing other types of video processing.  Have you looked at the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the resizer?

Comment: Yes I have read the documentation and may other sides a lot. But I cannot find the constraint to let the resizer work. The Video Processor MFT can do: "colorspace conversion, video resizing, deinterlacing, frame rate conversion, rotation, cropping, spatial left and right view unpacking, and mirroring."

Comment: I guess Video Processor(VP) couldn't perform resizing along with color conversion. It may be possible that VP MFT perform resizing, only when input and output pixel formats are same. It may be difficult for VP MFT node to understand the order i.e (Resize->color conv) or (Color Conv->Resize) and hence it possibly throwing error for resize operation for different input & output pixel formats.

Comment: Would it work to deploy 2 instances of the VideoProcessor MFT in your pipeline, in series, to each operate the resizing and color conversion functions separately?