# Resizing Texture before sending to SinkWriter SharpDX

Tags: directx, directx-11, ms-media-foundation, sharpdx, dxgi

I'm working on Screen recording application. My problem is I need to resize the Texure2d before making sample using CreateDXGISurfaceBuffer. I'm new with Mediafoundation and upon reading the documentation I couldn't find any sample code from the website. I'm using IDXGIOutput1::DuplicateOutput to get the screen texture. Is there a better way to resize the texture without suffering the performance?

Comment: Do you mean texture content interpolation or just texture dimensions change?

Comment: This is the actual scenario. I grab a full screen desktop image and store it to a texture with the exact dimension of screen resolution. what I need to do now is resize the texture before making media foundation sample. Its like rasterizing the texture with a new dimension. Could be bigger than original or smaller. I believe Video Processor MFT is the solution but I don't know where to start because it is my first time working with Media Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

[Video Processor MFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913) can scale your textures. When you use it in Direct3D 11 enabled mode, it scales using GPU. You feed `IMFSample` with textures and obtain `IMFSample` with scaled textures.

Even though it's not complete sample, [this code snippet](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/MediaFoundation/VideoProcessor01/Module.h#L161) might give an idea on interface methods involved.

You will also find related questions here on StackOverflow too:

- [How to properly use a hardware accelerated Media Foundation Source Reader to decode a video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913196/how-to-properly-use-a-hardware-accelerated-media-foundation-source-reader-to-dec)
- [Video resizing with the Video Processor MFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481417/video-resizing-with-the-video-processor-mft)